# rails facebook connect and new application settings editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Until lately, my application was working great with Facebook connect.

When you click on the `login with facebook` button, the popup shows up, and clicking `allow` does half its job:
Facebook connects to my secret controller that I set up in the Post-Authorize Callback URL, but instead of closing the popup and redirecting the user to the homepage, it shows the website in the popup.
The URL also looks weird; it includes a lot of variables:

```
http://dev2.mysite.com/?perms=email,user_birthday,user_location,read_friendlists&selected_profiles=.....&installed=1&session={%22session_key%22:%222.ngQ0..............2A__.3600.1283803200-573147092%22,%22uid%22:3.......3,%22expires%22:1283803200,%22secret%22:%22bMse.......sQ__%22,%22sig%22:%22f7446..........fafdfbeda%22}
```

I tried everything, but nothing's working.

I also checked that the xd_receiver is still present.

Also, all the tutorials I've looked through are talking about a connect tab and a connect URL field, but none are available anymore.
When I go to my application settings, I have only a Facebook integration tab
with the following fields:

- post authorize url: http://dev2.mysite.com/secret_controller_for_fb/
- Post-Authorize Redirect: http://dev2.mysite.com/
- canvas url: http://dev2.42pix.com/

Any help would be very appreciated!

---

After digging around, I found something interesting:

First, I'm not alone.

The example available at this page: http://big-glow-mama.heroku.com/ (git: http://github.com/holden/authlogic_openid_selector_example) suffers from the problem.

Also, when I change the `onlogin` value to: `document.location.href=document.location.href;`

the popup closes, refreshes the background, but does not login the user. I then need to click on the login button again to get logged in.

If any one has an idea, I'd love to hear from you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved to Oauth2 and everything looks fine now.

Answer (score 0):

And finally, I found something else,
the facebook connect button works well if you don't request any extended permissions otherwise it fails!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing helpful to offer Julien except that I am also seeing this same issue today. If I don't ask for extended permissions everything is fine. Must be some bug at the facebook end mustn't it?

Comment: When I didn't ask for extended permissions everything WAS fine, but rolling back to this point I still get redirected within the same window :-(

Comment: Yup, I get exactly the same error.
I kept on reading and found out that having your user getting authenticated this way isn't the best approach anymore. We should migrate our authentication/login process to Oauth2 which is the new authentication mecanism provided by Facebook. I keep on reading and I'll keep you posted if I find anything else interesting. You're welcome to do the same if you find anything too.

Comment: Will do, I have found that other people in the office are not seeing the same issue when following the same procedure (on my app, and on other sites that use facebook connect), just me. Something to do with having made a request for email once? Or being a facebook developer? It is not consistent...

Comment: fixing another issue by changing my development environment as per  http://www.techskater.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-engines-and-the-a-copy-of-applicationcontroller-has-been-removed-from-the-module-tree-but-is-still-active-error/comment-page-1/#comment-435 has made this issue go away, unless that is coincidence. I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing just my cookies doesn't help, but clearing my whole browser history makes this work again. Once.

Comment: I tried to login from many other computers and I ran into the same issue. I'm assuming facebook is migrating their facebook connect process to Oauth2 ...